# FileSystemWatcher event on adding a folder with subdirectories

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I'm using a FileSystemWatcher to monitor a directory for new folders created. This would work just fine, except that each of these folders can have one or more subdirectories inside of them.

The problem is that when I copy the top level folder (with one or more subdirectories in it) the FileSystemWatcher only catches the addition of the top level folder and not the subdirectories.

**Ex:** Drag folder 'foo' with subdirectory 'bar' into directory being watched
FileSystemWatcher notifies that new directory 'foo' was created, but says nothing about 'bar'

Am I missing something with the functionality of FileSystemWatcher or is there some other way around this?

Answer (score 9):

You also need to handle [OnRenamed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.onrenamed.aspx), as well as [IncludeSubdirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.includesubdirectories.aspx).

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx):

> **Copying and moving folders**
>
> The operating system and FileSystemWatcher object interpret a
>   cut-and-paste action or a move action as a rename action for a folder
>   and its contents. If you cut and paste a folder with files into a
>   folder being watched, the FileSystemWatcher object reports only the
>   folder as new, but not its contents because they are essentially only
>   renamed.
>
> To be notified that the contents of folders have been moved or copied
>   into a watched folder, provide OnChanged and OnRenamed event handler
>   methods...

Answer (score 4):

Setting IncludeSubdirectories does not work in this specific case.

Here's a sample i set up:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Temp", "*.*");

            fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            fsw.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(fsw_Created);
            fsw.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(fsw_Renamed);
            fsw.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(fsw_Changed);

            fsw.IncludeSubdirectories = true;

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void fsw_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} was changed.", e.FullPath);
        }

        static void fsw_Renamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} was renamed.", e.FullPath);
        }

        static void fsw_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} was created", e.FullPath);
        }
```

In this case, if i move foo that contains bar folder in it into C:\Temp, i will only be notified of C:\Temp\Foo created.

FileSystemWatcher is not sealed, if this functionality is vital, i would subclass it and extend it to check under created folders, and raise events for them as well (or something similar to this implementation).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [IncludeSudirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.includesubdirectories.aspx) which will get or set a value whether the subdirectories will be monitored.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `IncludeSubdirectories` property.

Take a look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.includesubdirectories%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

"Set IncludeSubdirectories to true when you want to watch for change notifications for files and directories contained within the directory specified"

```
watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you there is no way to tell the `FileSystemWatcher` to notify you for every element in a directory that has been changed.
If the element modified is a directory, you have to do the browsing on your own (which is not terribly hard).

`IncludeSubdirectories` only tells you about modifications of files and folders within the element watched - but alas not if it has been copied in in one move. In your example, when you watch *foo* and somebody adds a file to *bar* (later on) and you have set `IncludeSubdirectories` you will be notified of that change.

hth

Mario